# How to vertically align to top in a textinput (as3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, styles

I have the following code (textinput).

```
<s:TextInput id="label"                                                             
   text="just testing" 
   width="100%" 
   height="200"
   contentBackgroundColor="#aaaaaa"
   styleName="normalText">
</s:TextInput>
```

I am having a hard time finding how to align the text ("just testing") to the top.
I checked the Adobe documentation but it seems like there is no vertical alignment property available for this property.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextInput.html

I realize that there is a textarea component available but due to performance reasons, I need to use textinput.

topPadding seems to work for mx

```
 <mx:TextInput 
  id="txt" 
  paddingTop="5" 
  text="I am Vertically aligned text" 
  textAlign="center" 
  width="250" 
  height="250">
</mx:TextInput>
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick version

If the font size never varies, it may suffice to just work with `paddingBottom`. Because by default the vertical alignment is set to `middle`, decreasing  `paddingTop` alone will not suffice to move the text up sufficiently; it's set to 1px by default anyway. You'll have to increase `paddingBottom` too. I cannot give you exact numbers: it depends on the size of the font, so you'll have to play around with the values a bit.

```
<s:TextInput paddingBottom="6"/>
```

### Reusable version

If you want your solution to be reusable with any kind of font, you'll have to create a custom skin for TextInput. Fortunately, that's not too hard:

- Find the `spark.skins.spark.TextInputSkin`
- Copy it and give it a new name, say `my.skins.TopTextInputSkin`
- Find the `RichEditableText` tag with id `textDisplay` (it's at the bottom)
- Set its `verticalAlign` property to `top`
- Apply the new skin: `<s:TextInput skinClass="my.skins.TopTextInputSkin"/>`